# file field in drupal cck module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

How can I add a file field in drupal CCK ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download module **filefield** from here: http://drupal.org/project/filefield
enable it and you will see the field in the list of available field on the content type construction page.